# Error sending an implicit payment through Paypal Adaptive Payments API in node.js

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to send money from my business Paypal account to another Paypal account with the adaptive payments API.
I created a classical Paypal app, requested permissions to send implicit payment, and was Approved Conditionally.
I am using my business account's API UserId, password and signature, and when I make the payment request I use the email address associated with my business account.
It might be worth mentioning that it's a Swiss Paypal account.

Nevertheless, I receive an error:

```
[Error: Response ack is Failure. Check the response for more info]
{ responseEnvelope: 
   { timestamp: '2013-12-13T05:21:53.825-08:00',
     ack: 'Failure',
     correlationId: '6b31a6a7cbf80',
     build: '7935900' },
  error: 
   [ { errorId: '550001',
       domain: 'PLATFORM',
       subdomain: 'Application',
       severity: 'Error',
       category: 'Application',
       message: 'You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly' } ],
   httpStatusCode: 200 }
```

Here's my code:

```
Paypal = require 'paypal-adaptive'

paypalSdk = new Paypal
  userId    : 'my userId'
  password  : 'my password'
  signature : 'my signature'
  appId     : 'my appId'

payload =
  senderEmail : 'my email'
  requestEnvelope:
    errorLanguage: 'en_US'
  actionType    : 'PAY'
  currencyCode  : 'CHF'
  feesPayer     : 'EACHRECEIVER'
  memo          : 'example'
  returnUrl: "http://www.serviceathome.com?success=true"
  cancelUrl: "http://www.serviceathome.com?success=false"
  receiverList:
    receiver : [
      email: 'recipient email'
      amount: '1.00'
    ]

paypalSdk.pay payload, (err, res) ->
  if err?
    console.error err
    return console.error res

  console.log res
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: The solution was to wait for the approval. Even though the dashboard said it was "conditionally approved", it really wasn't. And the approval came a day later.

Answer (score 0):

Ita:    I had the same error just today.  I was using the sample code from the Paypal Adaptive Payments website exactly as shown.  I was simply entering the Paypal cURL snippet straight from the sample code.  I got the same command as you got.  I re-installed cURL and made sure the install the SSL cert.  Worked straight away after that.